# Unserialize data from a string with function maybe_unserialize

Tags: wordpress, function

I have a data array for displaying an image gallery. My problem is that all data from images are in a serialized string.

How can I to add the function maybe_unserialize and being able to nicely add data from that string?

```
<?php foreach( $dir_gallery as $dir_galleryimg ):?>
    <div class="ciGallery-item">
        Various HTML calling data from $dir_galleryimg.
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this way. It's doing the job, but maybe it's not the best way. Can you tell me?

```
 <?php foreach(array_slice($dir_gallery, 0, 1) as $dir_galleryimg ): 
       $meta = isset($dir_galleryimg->metadata) ? maybe_unserialize($dir_galleryimg->metadata) : '';?>
      <div class="ciGallery-item">
           content     
      </div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I am calling variable like this :

```
<?php echo esc_url($meta['sizes']['thumbnail']['file']); ?>
```